# Python panda merge is not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

Panda merge is not working as expected

I am using this code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Q1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "A2_1": [1, 2, 2, 1],
    "A2_2": [1, 1, 1, 1],
    "A2_3": [2, 2, 1, 1],
    "A2_4": [2, 2, 2, 1],
    "A3_1": [10, 25, 62, 18],
    "A3_2": [51, 51, 16, 17],
    "A3_3": [32, 23, 71, 31],
    "A3_4": [62, 52, 52, 11]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Melt DataFrame for A2
melted_a2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Q1"], value_vars=["A2_1", "A2_2", "A2_3", "A2_4"], var_name="A2", value_name="Value")

# Melt DataFrame for A3
melted_a3 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Q1"], value_vars=["A3_1", "A3_2", "A3_3", "A3_4"], var_name="A3", value_name="Value")

# Merge melted DataFrames on 'Q1'
result_df = pd.merge(melted_a2, melted_a3, on="Q1")

# Drop unnecessary columns
result_df.drop(columns=["A2", "A3"], inplace=True)

print(result_df)
```

and my expectation for output is

[image]

however the real output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

don need to use `melt` & `merge`.

```
tmp = df.set_index('Q1')
out = (tmp.set_axis(tmp.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1)
      .stack().sort_index(level=1).droplevel(1).reset_index()
)
```

out:

```
    Q1  A2  A3
0    1   1  10
1    2   2  25
2    3   2  62
3    4   1  18
4    1   1  51
5    2   1  51
6    3   1  16
7    4   1  17
8    1   2  32
9    2   2  23
10   3   1  71
11   4   1  31
12   1   2  62
13   2   2  52
14   3   2  52
15   4   1  11
```

---

or if you want make variable `tmp`, use following code:

```
out = (df.set_index('Q1')
       .set_axis(df.columns.drop('Q1').str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1)
       .stack().sort_index(level=1).droplevel(1).reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to `melted_a3` containing multiple rows for each `Q1` value from `melted_a2`, this ends up matching all of those rows having `Q1 = x` from `melted_a3` with each row in `melted_a2` that has `Q1 = x`, which ends up creating many more rows. In order to avoid this, you could remove duplicate rows (on `Q1`) from `melted_a3` before doing the merge:

```
>>> result_df = pd.merge(melted_a2, melted_a3.drop_duplicates(subset=['Q1']), on='Q1')
>>> result_df.drop(columns=['A2', 'A3'], inplace=True)
>>> result_df
    Q1  Value_x  Value_y
0    1        1       10
1    2        2       25
2    3        2       62
3    4        1       18
4    1        1       10
5    2        1       25
6    3        1       62
7    4        1       18
8    1        2       10
9    2        2       25
10   3        1       62
11   4        1       18
12   1        2       10
13   2        2       25
14   3        2       62
15   4        1       18
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a `melt` or `merge` (you are not creating any pair) but a simple reshaping for which you can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df, ['A2', 'A3'], i='Q1', j='j', sep='_')
         .reset_index().drop(columns='j')
         # optionally rename A2/A3
         .rename(columns={'A2': 'Value_x', 'A3': 'Value_y'})
      )
```

Or, manually specifying the columns to use for `Value_x`/`Value_y` with [`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html):

```
out = pd.lreshape(df, {'Value_x': ['A2_1', 'A2_2', 'A2_3', 'A2_4'],
                       'Value_y': ['A3_1', 'A3_2', 'A3_3', 'A3_4']})
```

Output:

```
    Q1  Value_x  Value_y
0    1        1       10
1    2        2       25
2    3        2       62
3    4        1       18
4    1        1       51
5    2        1       51
6    3        1       16
7    4        1       17
8    1        2       32
9    2        2       23
10   3        1       71
11   4        1       31
12   1        2       62
13   2        2       52
14   3        2       52
15   4        1       11
```

Intermediate after `wide_to_long`:

```
# pd.wide_to_long(df, ['A2', 'A3'], i='Q1', j='j', sep='_')
      A2  A3
Q1 j        
1  1   1  10
2  1   2  25
3  1   2  62
4  1   1  18
1  2   1  51
2  2   1  51
3  2   1  16
4  2   1  17
1  3   2  32
2  3   2  23
3  3   1  71
4  3   1  31
1  4   2  62
2  4   2  52
3  4   2  52
4  4   1  11
```